# React profile page, how to avoid 'GET http://localhost:3001/users/profile 401 (Unauthorized)' when trying to get JSON data from back end

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, jwt

For this application, I am using React & Express.  I have React running on PORT 3000, and Express running on PORT 3001.  On the Express side, I have authentication working that uses JWT.

First, here is my auth.js service file:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const models = require('../models');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var authService = {
    signUser: function (user) {
        const token = jwt.sign({
            Username: user.Username,
            UserId: user.UserId
        },
            'secretkey',
            {
                expiresIn: '1h'
            }
        );
        return token;
    },
    verifyUser: function (token) {
        try {
            let decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'secretkey');
            return models.users.findByPk(decoded.UserId);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return null;
        }
    },
    hashPassword: function (plainTextPassword) {
        let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
        let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(plainTextPassword, salt);
        return hash;
    },
    comparePasswords: function (plainTextPassword, hashedPassword) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(plainTextPassword, hashedPassword);
    }
}

module.exports = authService;
```

When a user makes a POST request to the signup route, it works:

```
router.post('/signup', function (req, res, next) {
  models.users.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      Username: req.body.username
    },
    defaults: {
      FirstName: req.body.firstName,
      LastName: req.body.lastName,
      Email: req.body.email,
      Password: authService.hashPassword(req.body.password)
    }
  })
    .spread(function (result, created) {
      if (created) {
        res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login");
      } else {
        res.send('This user already exist')
      }
    });
});
```

Signup works in both Postman and React.

When a user makes a POST request to the login route, it works:

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  models.users.findOne({
    where: {
      Username: req.body.username
    }
  }).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      console.log('User not found')
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Login Failed"
      });
    } else {
      let passwordMatch = authService.comparePasswords(req.body.password, user.Password);
      if (passwordMatch) {
        let token = authService.signUser(user);
        res.cookie('jwt', token);
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3001/users/profile');
      } else {
        console.log('Wrong Password');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Login works in both Postman and React.

When a user makes a GET request to the profile route, it semi-works:

```
router.get('/profile', function (req, res, next) {
  let token = req.cookies.jwt;
  if (token) {
    authService.verifyUser(token).then(user => {
      if (user) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(user));
      } else {
        res.status(401);
        res.send('Invalid authentication token');
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    res.send('Invalid authentication token');
  }
});
```

This works only in Postman, I can see the data that I want using Postman.  In React, it will not get the profile route that I request.  This is where the error comes in: [Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uicbp.png)

On the React side, this is profile GET component:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class UserProfile extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            profileData: []
        }
    };

    fetchProfileData = () => {
        var encodedURI = window.encodeURI(this.props.uri);
        return axios.get(encodedURI).then(response => {
            this.setState(() => {
                return {
                    profileData: response.data
                };
            });
        });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchProfileData();
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.profileData);
        if (this.state.profileData.length === 0) {
            return <div>Failed to fetch data from server</div>
        }

        const profile = this.state.profileData.map(user => (
            <div key={user.UserId}>Hello world</div>
        ));
        return <div>{profile}</div>
    }
}

export default UserProfile;
```

Then when I go to render this component, I just:

```
<UserProfile uri="http://localhost:3001/users/profile" />
```

Which then will render 'Failed to fetch data from server', then the console will log the '401 (Unauthorized)' error.  I just can't get it to render in React.

And if anyone wants my Express app.js file for some extra information:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var models = require('./models');
var cors = require('cors');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cors());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

models.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
  console.log("DB Synced Up");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Thank you in advanced.  I have been struggling to figure this out.

I have tried toying with my UserProfile component.  And I've tried toying with my /profile route in Express.  The only 2 errors I've gotten is the 401 (Unauthorized) and something about the Headers.  I know that my JWT key gets passed onto reacts side, because when I do 'localhost:3000/profile' (react side), I can see that I have the cookie stored.  I'm not sure on how to approach authorization on React side.  At this point, I am very clueless on what to do.  This is the first time I've tried setting up authentication with React.  I have always used Express and the .hbs files to render my profile pages.  But I've been told that you shouldn't render a profile page in the back-end.  So, here I am trying to do it with React.

I have rendered things from the back-end to the front-end, but that's without the use of JWT.  I strongly believe that it has something to do with the JWT cookie.  I just don't know how to authenticate it in React.  Thanks again in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding this into my React project:

### I added this into my fetchProfileData()

```
{ withCredentials: true }
```

---

```
    fetchProfileData = () => {
    var encodedURI = window.encodeURI(this.props.uri);
    return axios.get(encodedURI, { withCredentials: true }).then(response => {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                profileData: response.data
            };
        });
    });
};
```

Then in Express, I toyed with my Profile route.  Put the data into an array, and sent it on its way:

```
  router.get('/profile', function (req, res, next) {
    var userData = [];
    let token = req.cookies.jwt;
    if (token) {
      authService.verifyUser(token).then(user => {
        userData.push(user);
        res.send(userData);
      });
    } else {
      res.status(401);
      res.send('Invalid authentication token');
    }
 });
```